# I'm getting error message "This page isn’t working" in 123-reg windows server

Tags: asp.net, redirect, hosting

I getting error message **"This page isn’t working"**. When I hit this url "example.com" and when I hit this url "ipAddress/~example.com/index.html" it's working fine. I tried to resolve this error. Please help me.

Hosting company 123 reg
Hosting type windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your site works fine via IP but you can not access that from Domain name, it seems that you have a problem with the connection between your domain and host. Make sure that you have entered correct DNS records in domain control panel.